# How to exclude script files in angular.json?

Tags: angular, typescript

am developing a project in angular 6, I have some third party js files need to be used in .ts files, so i have added those in scripts array in angular.json.

angular.json

```
 "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "src/thirdParty/libs/localize.js",
          "src/thirdParty/libs/index.js"
        ]
```

and am using last two script files for development only not for production, Is there any way to exclude those 2 files in ng build ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can add  extra new project config in angular.json

Comment: extra project or extra server task which is used for development?